# Does this proof require unique readability?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

**I am wondering if this proof require unique readability? The proof is that every propositional formula has the same amount of left and right parantheses.**

We define the set of propositional formulas as the smallest X set such that:

- Every propositional variable is in X.
- If $F$ is in $X$ then $\neg F$ is in F.
- If $F$ and $G$ is in X, then $(F\land G), (F\lor G), (F\rightarrow G)$ is in X.

**Proof that every formula has the same amount of right and left paranthisis:**

Let $U$ be the set of propositional formulas with the same amount of left and right parantheses. Then every propositional variable is in $U$. If $F$ is in $U$ then $\neg F$ is in U since we add zero parantheses. And if $F$ and $G$ is in U, then $(F\land G), (F\lor G), (F\rightarrow G)$ is in U since we add one left and one right parantheses.  So we must have that $X\subset U$ since $X$ is the smallest set.

**Have I used unique readability in this proof? Or does it work without unique readability?**

**Definition of unique readability:**
Every propositional formula G is either

- a propositional variable
- $\neg F$ where $F$ is a propositional formula and $F$ is unique
- $H$ where $F$ and $G$ unique and $H=(F\land G)$ or $H=(F\lor G)$ or $H=(F\rightarrow G)$

Comment: The boldface looks like **shouting**.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what your concern is with regard to unique readability? Maybe first give a concrete example of unique readability vs non-unique readability?

Comment: @Bram28 I updated the question.

Comment: @user394334 Note how that definition of unique readability mirrors the definition of propositional formulas … meaning that every propositional formula is uniquely readable. So you get that for free.  But really you don’t have to worry about unique readability in the first place: your proof is a structural induction proof following the recursive definition of propositional logic formulas. And since you gad to prove this parenthesis theorem fir propositional logic formulas, you’re good, even if not all formulas would be uniquely readable.

Comment: @Karl Thank you, but I don't see where I use that. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: By the way, we're technically interpreting "the smallest set with the following properties" as "the intersection of all sets having the following properties". (That's how the definition ought to be stated, in my opinion.) This way, at the end of your proof we see that $U$ is one of the elements of the intersection, so $X\subseteq U$.

Comment: @Karl Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using unique readability. To see this, let us modify the definition of a formula in a way that keeps your proof intact, but destroys unique readability. What we can do for that is to add a new construction to obtain a formula:

- If $F,G,H \in X$, then also $((F \wedge G) \wedge H) \in X$.

Now when you see the formula $((F \wedge G) \wedge H)$, you no longer know whether it was obtained by using the original $\wedge$-construction twice, or the new one once. However, the proof regarding balanced parenthesis just needs an additional case, and it is still fine.

An alternative approach is to quotient the set of formulas. I can introduce the notion of a formula', which is defined just like a formula, except that the formulae' $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ are the same formula' (here $A$ and $B$ are particular propositional variables). This destroys unique readability, but your proof about balanced parenthesis again goes through for formula' just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! But regarding the last thing you wrote, why are $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ the same?

Comment: @user394334 Because I declared them to be. No other reason. (For a less frivolous example, consider how the fractions $\frac{2}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ are the same, while the pairs of numbers $(2,4)$ and $(1,2)$ are not.)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just one quick question regarding the formulae'. How does it work with the truth tables? Can you define $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ to allways be zero, and hence the same?

Comment: @user394334 Formulae' don't have truth values or anything. They are just an abstract concept, with the sole point to illustrate that unique readability is not needed in your proof.